# PHP jQuery calendar

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, calendar

Could some on recommend a good but simple calendar?

Functionality that I need is like in this site - http://www.macroeconomics.lv/ .

[image]

As you can see, if in date is a post or event then the date has gray background and if you hover on it you can see the post or event.

**I will try to modify it to display my coustom posts from wordpress, because I did not find any alternative wordpress plugin.**

Answer (score 1):

I think [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) may fits your need. it is jQuery based calender, you can add events, have full control of all events, a bunch of api is also well written, but it does NOT have the feature you posted here, which is what I want as well. if you know something similar, do let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is something like jQuery UI Datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker

This has good features, and a good documentation, and is quite easy to modify.

You can also chose different themes, and customise it to your needs.

Comment: Is it possible to add events to it?

Comment: @iKaspars what sort of events?